# Adding custom variable to $user object

Tags: 7, users

I am using the following to add a custom field to a user with a custom variable.

```
global $user;
  
$account = user_load($user->uid); 
 
$language = ($user->language) ? $user->language : 'und';
 
$edit = array(
  'field_favourite_football_team' => array(
    $language => array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => 'Manchester City',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
   
user_save($account, $edit);
```

**Problem**: I can see the outputted value on module A but on module B, when I dump or print out that global $user, I can't see that field. Is there anyway to save that on a for global use?

Comment: I think $user is a array, use print_r($user);

Comment: Use `$user = user_load($user->uid)` instead...

Comment: Dumb question: have you actually attached the field to the user entity? Admin >> Configuration >> People >> Account Settings >> Manage fields

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Oh bloody hell - i thought creating it with PHP was all that was required...?

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong - that worked. Thanks for the help all :)

Comment: I'll add this as an answer so you can accept it then.

Answer (score 1):

To add a field to the user entity, you need to visit the menu entry *Administration > Configuration > People > Account Settings > Manage Fields*. You can then define the field properties (including specifying whether it appears on the registration form or not) and customize how it is displayed on user pages.